# Beatifulsoup: how to find all elements 2nd parent of which has exact attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, beautifulsoup, anonymous-function

I have html structured like this:

```
<div class="value_i_need_to_match">
    <div>
        <a href="..."</a>
        <a href="..."</a>
        <a href="..."</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="some_other_value">
    <div>
        <a href="..."</a>
        <a href="..."</a>
        <a href="..."</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to extract all `<a>` elements second level parent of which has class attribute with value that matches to value_i_need_to_match. How to do this?
I tried:

```
 soup_post.find_all(
            lambda tag: tag.name == "a" and tag.parent.parent.find('div').attrs['class'] is 'value_i_need_to_match'))
```

and

```
soup_post.find_all(
            lambda tag: tag.name == "a" and tag.findParent('div').attrs["class"] == "value_i_need_to_match"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do that in a single go with a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup_post.select(".value_i_need_to_match > div > a")
```

where `>` means a direct parent-child relationship.

Comment: Won't work for me at the moment because I discovered that elements I want to get are not visible at DOM (they are loaded with JS after page load), but solution is correct and helpful, thanks. I just need to use find_all instead of select.